# MySQL extremely slow on a very simple query

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm getting very slow response running a very simple query in a small table (115k records)...
It takes about 8sec to respond, and I can't figure out why it's taking that long. Any advice would be awesome

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `financeiro_fluxo` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `branch` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `abertura` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `origem` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_pagamento` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `conta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tipo_lancamento` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `categoria` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tipo_entidade` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `entidade` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `entidade_input` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_pagamento` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parcela` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parcelas` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `valor` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `valor_taxa` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_troco` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmado` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_confirmacao` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `vencimento` date NOT NULL,
  `info` varchar(510) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `bandeira` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_add` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_last` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `param_ref` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `param` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `file` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=116749 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Query:

```
SELECT * from financeiro_fluxo
```

Explain:

```
id  select_type     table               type    key   key_len   rows   
1   SIMPLE          financeiro_fluxo    ALL                     116244
```

The same query running on localhost with the same table, returns in less than a sec...

Profile:

[image: Pofile:]

Comment: Check your InnoDB tuning. It's probably defaults which are terrible.

Comment: You try to obtain ~150Mbytes... read from disk, process, send to the client... it can be fast on the localhost, but on remote serser - hardly.

Comment: It is basically network time. The query always takes less than a sec (please confirm on show processlist) but then it takes 8 sec to transmit through the network to your client.

Comment: For a nightly, batch process a minute is perfectly acceptable. What's the problem? Now, you shouldn't be retrieving 100k rows interactively, should you?

Comment: @TheImpaler im getting data to generate dynamic reports, 8s is not that much, but im running others queries too...

Comment: Here's what happens: you're selecting *everything*. *Everything* varies in data. To squeeze everything through a pipe (network) it takes time. Time it takes depends on whether the pipe is fat (bandwith), whether the server is doing other things while trying to satisfy your request (such as using HDD for any reason, which can slow selects), whether there's enough memory to buffer the results your query produced (because it has to live somewhere until it's flushed down the pipe). So, what kind of answer are you after? You can't remove hardware limitations by using witty code.

Comment: (Unrelated)  A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key.  That is, your `UNIQUE(id)` is redundant and should be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are doing a full table scan because your query does not include any limiting conditions (for example WHERE clause or LIMIT). To let the query preform better use indexed columns with some kind of criteria. What happens if you add `WHERE id IS NOT NULL`

I assume you need all the records, if not limit the result set by added conditions in a more specific WHERE clause (on a indexed column) or a LIMIT clause.

Comment: It's not full table scan, it's full table **read**. Using `limit, offset` would still perform full table scan if there's no index candidate to reduce the data set being iterated.

Comment: About the full table scan, this says otherwise https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-scan-avoidance.html or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_full_table_scan That is your definition of a full table read and a full table scan?

Comment: So, first off - I hate nitpickers as much as you do. Second - the link you posted doesn't say otherwise. A scan means that each row is being read and then compared against some kind of condition (eg. `WHERE x LIKE '%text%'`). Full table scan means that the same has been done for every record. A full table read needs no conditions to work. There is no way that one can supply a condition that would make MySQL send the same data **faster** - which is what OP is after. You're trying to suggest strategies that you yourself don't really understand (`WHERE id IS NOT NULL` has 0 effect here).

Comment: @Rafanake Rule #1 Do not use SELECT * unless you will use every column.  
Rule #2 SELECT with no WHERE is asking for every row.  It is rare you can effectively use every column from any table for any on line system, unless you are trying to create a CSV type output data file. Recognize that a LOCALHOST system is usually faster than anything connected via the available connectors.

Comment: "Scan" vs "read" -- The bulk of the time in a _scan_ is spent _reading_ the rows.  That is, when discussing performance, there is not much difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

Will the "reports" aggregate data?  Of so, you could speed up the 8 second (remote) query by doing more work in the server, thereby shipping less data across the wire.

That is, think about whether `AVG(..), COUNT(*), SUM(..), MAX(..)`, etc can be done in the `SELECT`.

Taking that another step...  Build and maintain a "Summary table" that has subtotals (etc).  Then, reading (or scanning) the summary table and summing up the subtotals, etc, will be even faster, both in the Server and across the wire.

(And I agree with the need to avoid `*`, and that the 8 seconds is probably due to network delay (and "bandwidth").  Where is the server geographically?  How long does `SELECT 1;` take?)